# JavascriptMVC route examples

Tags: javascriptmvc

I am staring out with JavascriptMVC, and currently trying to figure out jQuery.route.  I know there are other 3rd party plugins that perform routing, but I'm specifically trying to figure out jQuery.route which comes with Javascript MVC.

I'm familiar with Backbone.js and Ember's routing frameworks, but I just don't understand JMVCs.  I've tried reading the documentation and looking at the code [here](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.route), but there are no examples and still can't figure it out.

I'm trying to do something basic such as, if the browser sees a URL like

```
http://localhost/helloWorld#state1
```

then some function will be executed.  Something similar to how Backbone and Ember work.  Can this be done using JavascriptMVC's jQuery.route?

Answer (score 0):

I think *[deparam](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.route.deparam)* should work for the task of figuring out the route for the current page:

```
var currentRoute = $.route.deparam(window.location.current);
if (currentRoute == "state1") {
    // handle route
}
```

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried.  Is there some additional line I need to init the router?  If I c+p your code, go to my page, at the root url, something like "localhost/helloWorld"  then change it to "localhost/helloWorld#state1"  nothing happens.   I did steal the required libs.

Comment: Hmm, that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Your previous answer using bind was more like it.  But I never was able to get the 'change' even to fire. In Ember, the router matches whatever is in the browser URL and executes a function.   Deparam won't return the currentRoute since it expects "key=value" as input.